# How do I make biblatex-chicago flow from one page to the next more often?

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I've noticed four things when writing my current essay:

1. LaTeX will automatically cause your title to be moved to the next page to avoid having the title and paragraph on separate pages
2. This on occasion leaves a really annoying amount of whitespace on a page, which is doubling annoying when you have a page limit.
3. biblatex-chicago will occasionally flow a citation from one page to the next automatically, but not very often.
4. Reading about Germany between 1933 and 1939 is really depressing.

Now 1 and 3 seem to suggest a solution to me:
Is it possible to get biblatex to reflow the citations more aggressively to reduce the amount of whitespace at the bottom of pages? Even if I wasn't fighting a page count, it always annoys me when I look at the two page spread and there is a massively different amount of whitespace at the bottom of the page.

Comment: You may want to look at the `bigfoot` package; it is supposed to do a better job of breaking footnotes across pages (it does a lot more than that, though).

Comment: But will that work with biblatex-chicago? I'm using the \autocite command and have no idea how that interacts with normal footnotes.

Comment: Shouldn't interfere, unless you use memoir, which has caused problems for me before (error messages, though the output was always OK).  Try: `\usepackage{bigfoot}` and `\DeclareNewFootnote{default}`.  I'm not sure how much help it'll give, but hope it does some --- and now I'm kind of curious!

Comment: @lockstep --- Done.  (Unfortunately, I don't have a ready example to test.)

Comment: Have you considered changing `\DeclareNewFottnote` to `\DeclareNewFootnote` (note the different spelling)?

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed that now and removed the erroneous bits form my question. I can't see any difference between the two outputs however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bigfoot](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bigfoot) is a comprehensive footnote package.  One of its features is that it is meant to do a better job splitting long footnotes.  I'm not sure how much help it will give for this problem, but it worth a shot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{lipsum,setspace}
   \doublespacing
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{default} 

% to quickly fix the setspace--bigfoot issue (mostly untested):
\makeatletter%
\def\@makefnstartbox{%
\reset@font\footnotesize
\singlespacing % <--- added; requires setspace.sty
\hsize\MFL@columnwidth \@parboxrestore
\interlinepenalty\FN@specific\FN@masterinsert\interfootnotelinepenalty
\widowpenalty\FN@specific\FN@masterinsert\footnotewidowpenalty
\clubpenalty\FN@specific\FN@masterinsert\footnoteclubpenalty
\advance\linepenalty500\relax}
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]%
\footnote{\lipsum[2]}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a note, the \DeclareNewFootnote{default} doesn't seem to do anything in my sample document, at least not anything visible, so I *think* you just have to load the package. Also note that bigfoot and setspace don't play nicely together by default, though I'm sure I (by which I mean TeX.SX) could make them work nicely if I still was working on this assignment.

Comment: @Canageek --- made a change so setspace works (probably). Do you get notified immediately or do I have to make a comment here..?

Comment: Nice: If I ever have this problem again I'll look this up. Next question: What does \DeclareNewFootnote do? Also: I get a notification in my control panel, but I get a big red thing at the top if you @ me.